# Single word or two or any substitution for "collection of movie titles"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing software to manage movies and TV shows which contain the list of titles seen by you. I need some name for it resembling something like:

- "**list of movies**"
- "**personal movie collection**"
- or "**a place where you keep your movie collection**"

Can anybody help me to find the correct phrase for it or the tell me where else to search for this?

Thanks

Comment: Just call it "movies". Too localised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  "movie rack", "my movie rack", "my movies", "my movie titles"

Comment: rack is nice :)....oops i cant upvote.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply "video library"? "Video" is more generic than "movie" (since you said it might include TV shows as well) and "library" means a collection of materials (videos in this case) that are kept for use but not for sale. Perhaps you could use "personal video library" to distinguish it from the term used for video rental stores (though they seem to be a dying breed these days).

Comment: It fine rather I myself had thought of such name but am in quest of something catchy...anyway thanks.